# Clojure importing nested classes

Tags: clojure, inner-classes

I am trying to write a couple of wrapper functions for the code [here](https://github.com/arangodb/java-velocypack/blob/master/src/main/java/com/arangodb/velocypack/VPackParser.java)

it basically has the form (as given in the example page) of

```
String json = ...
VPackParser parser = new VPackParser.Builder().build();
VPackSlice slice = parser.fromJson(json);
```

I am aware that To import inner classes one uses `$`, but every combination of the following doesn't seem to work.

```
(ns the.pain.is.real
  (:require [clojure.reflect :as r])
  (:import
   com.arangodb.velocypack.VPackBuilder ;; fine
   com.arangodb.velocypack.VPackSlice ;; fine
   com.arangodb.velocypack.VPackParser ;; fine
   com.arangodb.velocypack.VPack ;; fine
   com.arangodb.velocypack.VPackParser$Builder ;; nope
))
```

I just get a `Unhandled java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

I had worked with some similar code that I had got working using:

```
(ns winning
  (:import com.arangodb.ArangoDB$Builder))
(.build (-> (new ArangoDB$Builder)
            (.host "127.0.0.1" 8529)
            (.user username)
            (.password password)))
```

Any ideas?

looking in the jar file does show

`com/arangodb/velocypack/VPackParser$Builder.class`

Is it just trial and error?

Comment: If you look inside the jar file you should be able to see the exact names of the class files. Perhaps you won't find a `VPackParser$Builder` there.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy - ok. so it looks like there are 20 or so classes named ```com/arangodb/velocypack/VPackBuilder$8.class
com/arangodb/velocypack/VPackBuilder$9.class ...```

Comment: @ChrisMurphy - but I was looking at the wrong thing :( - yes there is one `com/arangodb/velocypack/VPackParser$Builder.class`

Comment: With Java I would always use a wildcard, so `com.arangodb.velocypack.*`, to make life simpler. Not sure if wildcards are possible for Clojure imports...

Comment: Unfortunately a wildcard import is not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990714/does-clojure-have-an-equivalent-of-javas-import-package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question.

It appears that two versions were downloaded when using `lein deps`. Even though only `[com.arangodb/velocypack "1.0.0"]` was in the project file, both `1.0.0` and `1.0.10` were in the `.m2` dir. The class `com/arangodb/velocypack/VPackParser$Builder.class` is only found in version `1.0.10`.

After changing the project file to `[com.arangodb/velocypack "1.0.10"]` the import works.